# Wordpress get the image from folder

Tags: wordpress, image, src

i have a code, to output the category and the count of posts in category.

what i want is to add an image from folder. the first category should get the "image1.jpg", the second "image2.jpg"

how to insert this to the existing code below?

```
?php

echo "<h2><a href=\"".$cat->category_nicename."\">".$cat->cat_name."</a></h2>
<?php $catID=the_category_ID(); ?><p>".$cat->category_description."(".$cat->category_count.")
</p></div>";
} ?>
```

thanks

Comment: You could try with this plugins. https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/, where you can able add/ remove images for category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this outside the while loop

```
$count = 1;
```

Then this is in the loop.

```
echo "<h2><a href=\"".$cat->category_nicename."\">".$cat->cat_name."</a></h2>";
echo "<img src=\"/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/image{$count}.jpg\">";
$catID=the_category_ID();
echo "<p>".$cat->category_description."(".$cat->category_count.")</p></div>";
$count += 1;
```

For each category the count should be incremented by 1.